# Swift 3 Timer in a Class not firing

Tags: swift, timer

I have a class:

```
class GameManager {...
```

and within it I have this func:

```
func startGame() {

        msgTimer = Timer(timeInterval: 0.5, target: self, selector: #selector(typeMessage(_:)), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

}
```

and the selector it calls:

```
@objc func typeMessage(_ sender:Timer) {

        if textCount > strInitText.characters.count {
            let strThisChar = strInitText[strInitText.index(strInitText.startIndex, offsetBy: textCount)]
            strDisplayText = strDisplayText + String(strThisChar)
            print(strDisplayText)
        }

    }
```

But the selector never gets called.

[image]

Comment: where are you calling startGame?

Comment: from my viewcontroller, this is the model for the viewcontroller in a VMMV pattern. - startGame does get called, I can put a break point there

Comment: Also why @objc ?
also can try removing objc if not required and calling selector as ->  

msgTimer = Timer(timeInterval: 0.5, target: self, selector: #selector(self. typeMessage), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

Comment: The IDE gives me an error without appending the @objc to the func. I think this is a bug in Xcode as I am not using any objective-c classes here. (Like NSTimer)

Comment: do you call `msgTimer.fire()` anywhere?

Comment: No, I was under the impression instantiating the timer would start it. @Ishika, check out my update to see the error message I am referring to.

Comment: I was able to get it to work by calling the fire method, but works and correct are two separate things

Comment: "I think this is a bug in Xcode as I am not using any objective-c classes here." Even though your code is written in Swift, Foundation and Cocoa are written in Objective-C. Timer is an "Objective-C class", and `#selector` is an Objective-C feature. You _must_ expose the selector method to Objective-C by marking it as `@objc`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Change

```
msgTimer = Timer(timeInterval: 0.5, target: self, selector: #selector(typeMessage(_:)), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

to

```
msgTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.5, target: self, selector: #selector(typeMessage(_:)), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

Comment: Your answer would be better if it explained _why_ this is necessary.

Comment: I am having this same issue in Swift 5.5 on macOS with essential the same setup.

Answer (score 10):

This timer needs to be scheduled on a run loop (via `-[NSRunLoop addTimer:]`) before it will fire.

And call it from the main thread as follows:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
        self?.msgTimer = Timer(timeInterval: 0.5, target: self, selector: #selector(self.typeMessage(_:)), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        RunLoop.current.add(self.msgTimer, forMode: RunLoopMode.commonModes)
}
```

However, I recommend you to use [scheduledTimer](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/timer/1412416-scheduledtimer) in this instance to remove this step:

> Creates a timer and schedules it on the current run loop in the default mode.

Be sure to invalidate the timer when you are done with it as follows:

```
self.msgTimer.invalidate()
```

Comment: this is a bit misleading. Using `RunLoop.current` inside a `DispatchQueue.main` is always the same as just using `RunLoop.main`

Comment: The comment about DIspatchQueue.main.async is the correct answer regarding the timer not firing.

Comment: This answer by Pranav is the correct answer for Swift 5 as well. It is the only code that will allow you to reuse a timer. I've made some edits to the code to help it properly invalidate as well.

Comment: I check whether or not the timer is being scheduled on the main thread and if not then the timer is scheduled on the main thread and it still is not working for me.